# Issues with declaring page variables - Razor

Tags: c#, variables, razor, cookies, webmatrix

I'm having issues with one of the pages on my site where I'm using a cookie value to pull some data out of my DB. It's working fine for my strings, but having issues with my integers and dates.

I start by declaring blank variables:

```
int numAdults;
```

I then check to see if a cookie is set, and if it is, I perform a database query (numAdults is data type int in the DB):

```
if(Request.Cookies["BookingReq"] != null){
    var breq = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM BookingRequests WHERE BookingGUID = @0", Request.Cookies["BookingReq"].Value);  
    numAdults = int.Parse(breq.NumAdults);        
}
```

The, in my form, I want to show as empty if the cookie isn't set, or show the "selected" option if it is:

```
<select class="form-control" id="numAdults" name="numAdults" @Validation.For("numAdults")>
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="0" selected="@(int.Parse(numAdults) == 0)">0</option>
    <option value="1" selected="@(int.Parse(numAdults) == 1)">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="@(int.Parse(numAdults) == 2)">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="@(int.Parse(numAdults) == 3)">3</option>
    <option value="4" selected="@(int.Parse(numAdults) == 4)">4</option>
</select>
```

This, however, leaves me with the following error when I run the page:

```
<option value="0" selected="@(numAdults == 0)">0</option>
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
```

Comment: `numAdults` is a string, not an int.

Comment: I've got a feeling i need to add an AsInt() in there somewhere, but i'm not sure where?

Comment: @(int.parse(numAdults) == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how WebMatrix is returning its dynamic result, but I think `breq.NumAdults` must actually be a string, otherwise it should error out when assigning to `numAdults`. (Confirm this by throwing a breakpoint on that line and inspecting `breq.NumAdults`).

It seems what you want to do is make `numAdults` an integer, then parse when retrieving from the database:

```
int numAdults; // Or pre-set this to zero if you need a default value.
...
numAdults = int.Parse(breq.NumAdults);
```

Comment: I'm not getting this error "<option value="0" selected="@(int.Parse(numAdults) == 0)">0</option>" --- The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Once your `numAdults` variable is an integer, then your original `@(numAdults == 0)` is fine, and you don't need the parse there.